# Формат даты в js

Tags: jquery, javascript

У меня есть пример кода:

```
$("#curday").click(function () {
    var newdate;
    date = new Date();
    newdate = date.getDate() + '.' + date.getMonth() + '.' + date.getFullYear();
    $("#datepicker_down").val(newdate);
});
```

Но у меня с ним есть проблемы.

1. У месяца вывод начинается с нуля, то есть я сейчас имею 7-й месяц, а не 8-й, как это подправить?
2. Формат вывода даты получается такой: 20.7.2012, а хочется получить вот такой: 20.07.2012, то есть чтобы если у числа и месяца если 1 цифра, то впереди автоматом дописывался ноль.

Прошу помочь в этих нюансах. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Я бы посоветовал не ломать голову, а подключить библиотеку [datejs](http://www.datejs.com/)
Тогда пожно написать

```
$("#datepicker_down").val( (new Date()).toString('dd.MM.yyyy') );
```

Comment: А эта библиотека умеет делать ? текущий день, завтрашний день, через неделю ? что бы автоматом подставлять правильные значения ?

Comment: Добавлю, что по прошествии времени использую momentjs. А в случае простых вариантов, самописные функции.

Answer (score 15):

Так как я ленивый, то собирать дату вручную облом )) Поэтому подключаем [этот скриптик](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B-FCjMFmnZuxT1BQNmVjTENMV0E), далее к прототипу класса Data добавляется метод format, выполняющий форматирование даты в соответствии с переданным шаблоном:

```
Date.prototype.format = function (mask, utc) {
    return dateFormat(this, mask, utc);
};
```

А теперь, измываемся над датой как угодно:

```
var now = new Date();
now.format("m/dd/yy"); // 8/20/12
now.format("dd.mm.yyyy"); // 20.08.2012
now.format("dd mmm"); // 20 Aug
now.format("ddd mmm dd yyyy HH:MM:ss"); // Mon Aug 20 2012 09:06:56
now.format("h:MM:ss TT"); // 9:08:39 AM
// и т.д.
```

Смотрим [пример тут](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/QpLNC/)

UPD: под катом код, который по ссылке

```js
/*
 * Date Format 1.2.3
 * (c) 2007-2009 Steven Levithan <stevenlevithan.com>
 * MIT license
 *
 * Includes enhancements by Scott Trenda <scott.trenda.net>
 * and Kris Kowal <cixar.com/~kris.kowal/>
 *
 * Accepts a date, a mask, or a date and a mask.
 * Returns a formatted version of the given date.
 * The date defaults to the current date/time.
 * The mask defaults to dateFormat.masks.default.
 */

var dateFormat = function () {
 var token = /d{1,4}|m{1,4}|yy(?:yy)?|([HhMsTt])\1?|[LloSZ]|"[^"]*"|'[^']*'/g,
  timezone = /\b(?:[PMCEA][SDP]T|(?:Pacific|Mountain|Central|Eastern|Atlantic) (?:Standard|Daylight|Prevailing) Time|(?:GMT|UTC)(?:[-+]\d{4})?)\b/g,
  timezoneClip = /[^-+\dA-Z]/g,
  pad = function (val, len) {
   val = String(val);
   len = len || 2;
   while (val.length < len) val = "0" + val;
   return val;
  };

 // Regexes and supporting functions are cached through closure
 return function (date, mask, utc) {
  var dF = dateFormat;

  // You can't provide utc if you skip other args (use the "UTC:" mask prefix)
  if (arguments.length == 1 && Object.prototype.toString.call(date) == "[object String]" && !/\d/.test(date)) {
   mask = date;
   date = undefined;
  }

  // Passing date through Date applies Date.parse, if necessary
  date = date ? new Date(date) : new Date;
  if (isNaN(date)) throw SyntaxError("invalid date");

  mask = String(dF.masks[mask] || mask || dF.masks["default"]);

  // Allow setting the utc argument via the mask
  if (mask.slice(0, 4) == "UTC:") {
   mask = mask.slice(4);
   utc = true;
  }

  var _ = utc ? "getUTC" : "get",
   d = date[_ + "Date"](),
   D = date[_ + "Day"](),
   m = date[_ + "Month"](),
   y = date[_ + "FullYear"](),
   H = date[_ + "Hours"](),
   M = date[_ + "Minutes"](),
   s = date[_ + "Seconds"](),
   L = date[_ + "Milliseconds"](),
   o = utc ? 0 : date.getTimezoneOffset(),
   flags = {
    d:    d,
    dd:   pad(d),
    ddd:  dF.i18n.dayNames[D],
    dddd: dF.i18n.dayNames[D + 7],
    m:    m + 1,
    mm:   pad(m + 1),
    mmm:  dF.i18n.monthNames[m],
    mmmm: dF.i18n.monthNames[m + 12],
    yy:   String(y).slice(2),
    yyyy: y,
    h:    H % 12 || 12,
    hh:   pad(H % 12 || 12),
    H:    H,
    HH:   pad(H),
    M:    M,
    MM:   pad(M),
    s:    s,
    ss:   pad(s),
    l:    pad(L, 3),
    L:    pad(L > 99 ? Math.round(L / 10) : L),
    t:    H < 12 ? "a"  : "p",
    tt:   H < 12 ? "am" : "pm",
    T:    H < 12 ? "A"  : "P",
    TT:   H < 12 ? "AM" : "PM",
    Z:    utc ? "UTC" : (String(date).match(timezone) || [""]).pop().replace(timezoneClip, ""),
    o:    (o > 0 ? "-" : "+") + pad(Math.floor(Math.abs(o) / 60) * 100 + Math.abs(o) % 60, 4),
    S:    ["th", "st", "nd", "rd"][d % 10 > 3 ? 0 : (d % 100 - d % 10 != 10) * d % 10]
   };

  return mask.replace(token, function ($0) {
   return $0 in flags ? flags[$0] : $0.slice(1, $0.length - 1);
  });
 };
}();

// Some common format strings
dateFormat.masks = {
 "default":      "ddd mmm dd yyyy HH:MM:ss",
 shortDate:      "m/d/yy",
 mediumDate:     "mmm d, yyyy",
 longDate:       "mmmm d, yyyy",
 fullDate:       "dddd, mmmm d, yyyy",
 shortTime:      "h:MM TT",
 mediumTime:     "h:MM:ss TT",
 longTime:       "h:MM:ss TT Z",
 isoDate:        "yyyy-mm-dd",
 isoTime:        "HH:MM:ss",
 isoDateTime:    "yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:MM:ss",
 isoUtcDateTime: "UTC:yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:MM:ss'Z'"
};

// Internationalization strings
dateFormat.i18n = {
 dayNames: [
  "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat",
  "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"
 ],
 monthNames: [
  "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec",
  "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
 ]
};

// For convenience...
Date.prototype.format = function (mask, utc) {
 return dateFormat(this, mask, utc);
};
```

Answer (score 11):

```js
var options = {
 year: 'numeric',
 month: 'numeric',
 day: 'numeric',
 timezone: 'UTC'
};

alert(new Date().toLocaleString("ru", options));
// 20.07.2012
```

Answer (score 7):

Про тернарный оператор слышали?

```
var month = date.getMonth()+1;   
newdate = date.getDate() + '.' 
          + (month < 10 ? '0' : '') + month + '.' 
          + date.getFullYear();
```

Для работы со временем есть отличная библиотека [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

Answer (score -2):

```
/**
* Функция добавления к дате date несколько дней указанных в days  
* @param date
* @param days
* @return string 
*/
window.dateAdd = function(date, days){
    var dateParsed = date.match(/(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2})-(\d{2,4})/);
    var date = new Date(dateParsed[3],dateParsed[2],dateParsed[1]);
    var day =   date.getDate()+1; 
    var month = date.getMonth();
    var year =  date.getFullYear();        

    if(date<10) date = "0"+date;
    if(month<10) month = "0"+month;

    var newdateStr = day + '-' + month + '-' + year;

    return newdateStr;
}
```

Comment: я поправил форматирование, не надо вставлять сниппет, который при запуске ничего не делает, в данном случае нужно использовать блок кода

Comment: Какое отношение эта функция имеет к форматированию даты?