# Вопрос преобразования типов в датах

Tags: javascript

Получаю в JS переменную дату из msql DATETIME ввиде
2017-01-25 20:28:10
var supertime = "2017-01-25 20:28:10" - это строка, не дата.

Мне нужно преобразовать в 01.25 20:28

Как можно это сделать проще чем регулярные выражения?
Как поменять формат вывода даты, где данные даты лежать в стринговой строке JS

Дату я получаю json строкой в js, по-этому можно менять как в JS так и на стадии формирования строки в php когда вытащил из базы.

Comment: Вы определитесь с типами. И ещё - помните, что значение и его отображение - это совершенно разные вещи. Попробуйте обойтись штатными средствами форматирования вывода - например, может подойти _dateObj.toLocaleString()_ ...

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Формат даты в js](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/138337/%d0%a4%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b2-js)

Comment: Для dateObj.toLocaleString() у Вас должна быть переменная типа "time", а у меня string

Answer (score 1):

Может попробовать сразу в запросе преобразовать в нужный формат через [DATE_FORMAT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp) ?

Например:

```
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m-%d-%Y %h:%i') // 26-01-2017 19:18
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$item = "2017-01-25 20:28:10"; // из MSQL
$time = strtotime($item);
$item = date( 'd',$time ).'.'.date( 'm',$time ).' '.date( 'H',$time ).':'.date( 'i',$time );  // получаем 25.01 20:28
```