# Как получить первый и последний день месяца? Проблема со сдвигом временной зоны

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно получать начало и конец месяца в формате YYYY.MM.DD.HH.MM.SS, формат как пример точности времени.

```
let dateNow = new Date(); //2017-05-15T17:00:37.982Z

let getYear = dateNow.getFullYear(); //2017
let getMonth = dateNow.getMonth(); //4 т.к. месяцы с нуля то все ок

let startDate = new Date(getYear, getMonth, 1); 
//2017-04-30T21:00:00.000Z идет сдвиг месяца на -1, число 30 вместо 1, часы 21

let stopDate = new Date(getYear, getMonth, 0, 23, 59, 59); 
//2017-04-30T20:59:59.000Z идет сдвиг месяца на -1 часа на -3
```

Непонятно что с месяцем, почему он стал апрелем и с временем.
Читал про UTC, а как быть если пользователи с разных часовых поясов?

Comment: Возможно по месяцу : let startDate = new Date(getYear, getMonth, 1); вы же пишете  - //4 т.к. месяцы с нуля то все ок. Значит  - let startDate = new Date(getYear, getMonth + 1, 1); получите 5 месяц

Comment: @Eikhner ну я так понимаю это должно работать в обе стороны. И вот пример https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Examples

Comment: month:
Целое значение, представляющее месяц, начинается с 0 для января и кончается 11 для декабря. По итогу  - 
0 для первого месяца и 11 для последнего -12 го.

Comment: @Eikhner И? 0 == Январь, ..., 4 == Май

Answer (score 0, accepted):

может вам подойдет [вот это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/138337/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B2-js)

[здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/datetime) читаем  - работает , 
а так

```js
var date = new Date(2011, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 567);
console.log( date ); // 1.01.2011, 02:03:04.567
```

не работает , тоже не понятно

а вот так заработало

```js
var options = {
 year: 'numeric',
 month: 'numeric',
 day: 'numeric',
 timezone: 'UTC'
};
var startDate = new Date(2017, 4, 1);
console.log(startDate.toLocaleString("ru", options));
```

Comment: Будем считать ответ принятым. Хотя я все-таки взял moment.js слишком уж он удобный, хотя я и не хотел использовать лишних библиотек.